# glossaries-extra: Roman and arabic numbers wrongly sorted

Tags: page-numbering, glossaries, sorting, glossaries-extra

Feeding

```
\documentclass{book}%%% for debugging only. For production, I use svmono.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[makeindex,toc,nogroupskip,nomain]{glossaries-extra}%%% similar issue with glossaries
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{not:powerset}{type=notation, name={\(\mathfrak{P}\)}, text={\mathfrak{P}}, sort={powerset}, description={The power set of a set \(Z\) is denoted by \(\mathfrak{P}(Z)\).}}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}\(\gls{not:powerset}\)
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}\(\gls{not:powerset}\)
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

to a loop over `pdflatex mwe && makeglossaries mwe` results in a wrong page order in the glossary when using TeXLive 2022 (as opposed to TeXLive 2021, where the order was o.k.):

[image: output]

The page order in the third column should be “I, 1” rather than “1, I” because the Roman-numbered pages occur before the arabic-numbered pages in the document.  Is it a bug or a feature of glossaries-extra?  How do I get the page order right?

Comment: I think (am not sure), this is a limitation of `makeindex`. The user manual for `makeindex` states that "MakeIndex assumes that all page numbers are either arabic or lowercase roman numerals; it assumes that pages numbered with roman numerals
precede those numbered with arabic numerals." I would suggest trying (i) with `\roman` instead of `\Roman` in your front matter to see if this indeed the cause and (ii) try using `xindy` instead of `makeindex` to see if it helps with this problem.

Comment: The [documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:xindyloc) suggests that with the xindy backend you can change the ordering of different ranges of numbers. (Default has roman before arabic before Roman.) Search for `\GlsSetXdyLocationClassOrder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`makeindex` made some changes in the ordering of page numbers. You can change the ordering with `page_precedence` in the `.ist` file. With glossaries for example you could do this:

```
\documentclass{book}%%% for debugging only. For production, I use svmono.
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[makeindex,toc,nogroupskip,nomain]{glossaries-extra}%%% similar issue with glossaries
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}
\GlsSetWriteIstHook{%
\write\glswrite{page_precedence "Rn"}% Roman then numbers
}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{not:powerset}{type=notation, name={\(\mathfrak{P}\)}, text={\mathfrak{P}}, sort={powerset}, description={The power set of a set \(Z\) is denoted by \(\mathfrak{P}(Z)\).}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Roman}\(\gls{not:powerset}\)
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}\(\gls{not:powerset}\)
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm; thank you!